# Error runnning JavaDoc: Cannot generate JavaDoc, jdk path is not specified or invalid

Tags: java, javadoc, document

I am trying to generate a **JavaDoc** in intellij idea and i cannot fix the error.

I'v tried to fix it by add a new path to (Documentation Paths <- SDKs <- Project Structure <- File) but didn't work.
I set the path into jbr folder but

Comment: Which document you are trying to generate and also can you share the error as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the selected JDK path in your Project Structure popup:
[File->Project Structure->Platform Settings->SDKs]
and specify required path
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I changed my folder names (they weren't in English), then the path was ok.
I think it applies to special characters as well.